# Как отсортировать массив

Tags: массивы, сортировка, swift3

Есть массив:

```
let arrayDate = [
    "Sat, 26 November, 22:40",
    "Fri, 20 January, 00:18",
    "Mon, 26 December, 22:40",
    "Sat, 07 January, 00:10",
    "Sun, 12 February, 22:40",
    "Sun, 15 January, 22:40",
    "Thu, 26 January, 00:20"
]
```

как его отсортировать в порядке возрастания даты, сверху вниз или снизу вверх?

Comment: В чём именно вы видите проблему, какие подходы используете и что хотите видеть в ответе?

Comment: В ответе хочу видеть упорядоченный массив по дате: "Sat, 07 January, 00:10", "Sun, 15 January, 22:40", "Fri, 20 January, 00:18","Thu, 26 January, 00:20","Sun, 12 February, 22:40","Sat, 26 November, 22:40", "Mon, 26 December, 22:40"

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример:

```
let arrayDate = [
    "Sat, 26 November, 22:40",
    "Fri, 20 January, 00:18",
    "Mon, 26 December, 22:40",
    "Sat, 07 January, 00:10",
    "Sun, 12 February, 22:40",
    "Sun, 15 January, 22:40",
    "Thu, 26 January, 00:20"
]

arrayDate.sort(function(a,b){
  var c = new Date(a);
  var d = new Date(b);
  return c-d;
});
```

Comment: Проясните пожалуйста, я начинающий!